# How to invoke a function passed into another function only 2 times?

Tags: javascript, callback, closures

I am trying to invoke a function passed into another function only 2 times. My solution is wrong and any help would be appreciated!

```
function twoTimes(func){
 var count=0;
 for (var i=0; i<=2; i++){
 count++;
 if (count<2){
  return func();
}

 }
}
```

Comment: Well you can not execute the loop twice if you execute a return. Not sure why you need the count  when you are looping.

Comment: Not sure why this is tagged to closures

Answer (score 1):

I think you just shouldn't use `return` statement, until it was called two times. Try it without the `return` statement.
Or you can use some simple method, like this :

```
function twoTimes(func){
 func();
 func();
}
```

Comment: Another thing to consider would be that even if the return wasn't there, you would only execute the function once anyways because of the mismatched conditionals. Try

Answer (score 1):

Here is one simpler possibility.

Another thing to consider would be that even if the return wasn't there, you would only execute the function once anyways because of the mismatched conditionals. Try

```
function nTimes(func, n){
    for (var i=0; i<n; i++){
         func();
    }
}
```

Notice that the `count` from your example was unnecessary. Since you already had `i`, `count` was just extra work.

Take a closer look at http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_functions.asp to gain a little more familiarity!